# pg.rb segmentation fault [Mojave upgrade]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Segmentation fault in pg.rb:56

versions:
rails: 5.2.0,
ruby: 2.4.4,
pg gem: 0.20.0

After upgrading to Mac OS mojave i have encountered problems with my local host server. The server itself, starts fine, however when trying to access it through a web browser, it crashes and I have the segmentation error shown above.

Comment: Try reinstalling the `pg` gem - this should recompile the native code with the current libraries on Mojave.

Comment: Thanks of the help, I have tried that but unfortunately it does not work. After digging around a little I have found that when I remove the puma gem from the app, and the server runs with WEBrick, it loads fine and no segmentation fault.

Comment: puma also has some native extensions - have you tried reinstalling the puma gem as well?

Comment: Yeah, I have tried reinstalling the puma gem and reinstalling the gem to the latest version.

Comment: I have narrowed it down to the `workers ENV.fetch("WEB_CONCURRENCY") { 2 }` line in my puma.rb file. Do you know why this could be causing a segfault ?

Comment: How did you proceed?

Comment: The problem seems to be running puma in multi connection mode. Option 1: updating ruby worked but wasn't the best option for me at the time, Option 2: Setting the workers to 1, meaning puma was in single user mode in my dev environment. 

`workers_count = Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 1)
if workers_count > 1
  workers workers_count`

Comment: For me the sefault is only happening in rails console, not when running webserver (all in development)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As this issue is only occuring in the development environment, I made it conditional. This solution in `puma.rb` works for me until the bug gets fixed.

`workers ENV.fetch("WEB_CONCURRENCY") { 2 } unless Rails.env.development?`

Comment: This fixed it for me. I don't understand what the actual issue is here, if you do, would you mind putting a link to it so we can track it?

Comment: This worked for me as well. And to clarify, the fix is in `config/puma.rb`.

Answer (score 5):

in .env file set 
`WEB_CONCURRENCY=0`
and you do not need to add any logic in config/puma.rb

Comment: This, of course, if _dotenv_ is being used. But it's a good idea!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, in which my test environment was often crashing in Ruby 2.6.3 with Segmnentation Fault lib/pg.rb line 56.

What worked for me was setting pumb.rb to have zero workers in the test environment:

```rb
# config/puma.rb
(ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") == 'test') ? (workers 0) : (workers ENV.fetch("WEB_CONCURRENCY") { 2 })
```