# How can I find the source of my Rails app crashing after first request from client (pg.rb segmentation fault) after an upgrade to macOS Mojave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, puma, macos-mojave

After updating my Mac OS to Mojave, I encountered this problem in **only 1**  of the Rails applications on my machine. I can't make sense out of the thousands of lines. Here is the beginning of the stack trace. I can start the rails server but with the first request, this crash report shows up. It might have something to do with Postgres. But I use the same configuration for my other apps as well.

I am using Rails 5.2.1 with Ruby 2.5.1.

```
[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

[IMPORTANT]
Don't forget to include the Crash Report log file under
DiagnosticReports directory in bug reports.

Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-12-17 17:51:38 +0100
/Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pg-1.1.3/lib/pg.rb:56: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x000000010b42da3a
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-darwin17]

-- Crash Report log information --------------------------------------------
   See Crash Report log file under the one of following:                    
     * ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports                                     
     * /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports                                      
   for more details.                                                        
Don't forget to include the above Crash Report log file in bug reports.     

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0054 p:---- s:0374 e:000373 CFUNC  :initialize
c:0053 p:---- s:0371 e:000370 CFUNC  :new
c:0052 p:0016 s:0366 e:000365 METHOD /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pg-1.1.3/lib/pg.rb:56
c:0051 p:0013 s:0361 e:000360 METHOD /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresq
c:0050 p:0030 s:0356 e:000355 METHOD /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresq [FINISH]
```

Comment: this link probably can help you https://stackoverflow.com/q/53046623/938947

Comment: Ah, perfect! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

I found a temporary fix for this issue and already posted a solution here: [pg.rb segmentation fault [Mojave upgrade]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53046623/pg-rb-segmentation-fault-mojave-upgrade)

The crash is puma-related and I managed to fix it like this in `puma.rb`:

`workers ENV.fetch("WEB_CONCURRENCY") { 2 } unless Rails.env.development?`

Comment: Or just set WEB_CONCURRENCY=0 in your local .env.