# Running rspec prints out process memory map and list of files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rspec, memory-mapped-files

When running my rspec tests, instead of them running as usual, they print out the process memory map:

```
    1030a8000-1030b8000 r-- /opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql/13.2_2/lib/libpq.5.13.dylib
1030b8000-1030ec000 r-x /opt/homebrew/Cellar/krb5/1.19.1/lib/libgssapi_krb5.2.2.dylib
1030ec000-1030f0000 r-- /opt/homebrew/Cellar/krb5/1.19.1/lib/libgssapi_krb5.2.2.dylib
1030f0000-1030f4000 rw- /opt/homebrew/Cellar/krb5/1.19.1/lib/libgssapi_krb5.2.2.dylib
1030f4000-103108000 r-- /opt/homebrew/Cellar/krb5/1.19.1/lib/libgssapi_krb5.2.2.dylib
103108000-103188000 r-x /opt/homebrew/Cellar/krb5/1.19.1/lib/libkrb5.3.3.dylib
103188000-103194000 r-- /opt/homebrew/Cellar/krb5/1.19.1/lib/libkrb5.3.3.dylib
103194000-103198000 rw- /opt/homebrew/Cellar/krb5/1.19.1/lib/libkrb5.3.3.dylib
103198000-1031cc000 r-- /opt/homebrew/Cellar/krb5/1.19.1/lib/libkrb5.3.3.dylib
1031cc000-1031f0000 r-x /opt/homebrew/Cellar/krb5/1.19.1/lib/libk5crypto.3.1.dylib
1031f0000-1031f4000 r-- /opt/homebrew/Cellar/krb5/1.19.1/lib/libk5crypto.3.1.dylib
1031f4000-1031f8000 rw- /opt/homebrew/Cellar/krb5/1.19.1/lib/libk5crypto.3.1.dylib
1031f8000-103204000 r-- /opt/homebrew/Cellar/krb5/1.19.1/lib/libk5crypto.3.1.dylib
103204000-103208000 r-x /opt/homebrew/Cellar/krb5/1.19.1/lib/libcom_err.3.0.dylib
103208000-10320c000 r-- /opt/homebrew/Cellar/krb5/1.19.1/lib/libcom_err.3.0.dylib
10320c000-103210000 rw- /opt/homebrew/Cellar/krb5/1.19.1/lib/libcom_err.3.0.dylib
103210000-103218000 r-- /opt/homebrew/Cellar/krb5/1.19.1/lib/libcom_err.3.0.dylib
103218000-103220000 r-x /opt/homebrew/Cellar/krb5/1.19.1/lib/libkrb5support.1.1.dylib
103220000-103224000 r-- /opt/homebrew/Cellar/krb5/1.19.1/lib/libkrb5support.1.1.dylib
103224000-103228000 rw- /opt/homebrew/Cellar/krb5/1.19.1/lib/libkrb5support.1.1.dylib
103228000-103230000 r-- /opt/homebrew/Cellar/krb5/1.19.1/lib/libkrb5support.1.1.dylib
103230000-103238000 r-x /Users/marlomajor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/bcrypt-3.1.16/lib/bcrypt_ext.bundle
103238000-10323c000 r-- /Users/marlomajor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/bcrypt-3.1.16/lib/bcrypt_ext.bundle
10323c000-103240000 rw- /Users/marlomajor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/bcrypt-3.1.16/lib/bcrypt_ext.bundle
103240000-103244000 r-- /Users/marlomajor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/bcrypt-3.1.16/lib/bcrypt_ext.bundle
103244000-103248000 r-x /Users/marlomajor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/arm64-darwin20/enc/iso_8859_1.bundle
103248000-10324c000 r-- /Users/marlomajor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/arm64-darwin20/enc/iso_8859_1.bundle
10324c000-103250000 rw- /Users/marlomajor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/arm64-darwin20/enc/iso_8859_1.bundle
103250000-103254000 r-- /Users/marlomajor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/arm64-darwin20/enc/iso_8859_1.bundle
103254000-10325c000 r-x /Users/marlomajor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/arm64-darwin20/objspace.bundle
10325c000-103260000 r-- /Users/marlomajor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/arm64-darwin20/objspace.bundle
103260000-103264000 rw- /Users/marlomajor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/arm64-darwin20/objspace.bundle
103264000-10326c000 r-- /Users/marlomajor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/arm64-darwin20/objspace.bundle
10326c000-103270000 r-x /Users/marlomajor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/arm64-darwin20/io/console.bundle
```

This is what the error looks like. Then it ends with:

```
180000000-190000000 r--
190000000-1a0000000 r--
1a0000000-1b0000000 r--
1b0000000-1c0000000 r--
1c0000000-1d0000000 r--
1d0000000-1e0000000 r--
1e0000000-1f0000000 r--
1f0000000-1f8000000 r--
1f8000000-1fa000000 rw-
1fa000000-1fc000000 r--
1fc000000-1fdd1c000 r--
1fdd1c000-203590000 rw-
203590000-204000000 r--
204000000-210000000 r--
210000000-220000000 r--
220000000-230000000 r--
230000000-240000000 r--
240000000-250000000 r--
250000000-260000000 r--
260000000-270000000 r--
270000000-280000000 r--
fc0000000-1000000000 ---
1000000000-7000000000 ---
[IMPORTANT]
Don't forget to include the Crash Report log file under
DiagnosticReports directory in bug reports.
```

I've reinstalled ruby, rails, postgresql, rubyset, and upgraded brew, spring, and upgraded all gems.

Here's the beginning of the diagnostic report:

```
Process:               ruby [1621]
Path:                  /Users/USER/*/ruby
Identifier:            ruby
Version:               0
Code Type:             ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        zsh [585]
Responsible:           iTerm2 [582]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2021-05-04 10:51:09.396 -0600
OS Version:            macOS 11.2 (20D64)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        30E89EB2-8010-0620-90B2-D5C8316666A7


Time Awake Since Boot: 710 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

VM Regions Near 0:
--> 
    __TEXT                      10051c000-100520000    [   16K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  /Users/*

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
```

Comment: how do you solved it?

Comment: I found a solution for my error that's similar to yours https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53046623/pg-rb-segmentation-fault-mojave-upgrade